# ggplot facet_wrap + multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

This is my data I am working with:

```
structure(list(Substrate = c("Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", "Glukoza", 
"Glukoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", 
"Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Manoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", "Galaktoza", 
"Galaktoza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", 
"Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Ksiloza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", 
"Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Arabinoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", "Ramnoza", 
"Ramnoza", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", 
"Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Gal kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", 
"Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina", "Glu kislina"
), Strain = c("Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", 
"Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", 
"Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Pr"), Time = c(1L, 
5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 
72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 
24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 
12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 
1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 
48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 
14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 
5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 
72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 
24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 
12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 
1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 
48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 
14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 
5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 
72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 
24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 
12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 
1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 
48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 
14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 
5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 
72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 
24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 
12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 
1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 
48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 
14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 
5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 
72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 
24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 
12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 
1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 
48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 
14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 
5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 
72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 
24L, 48L, 72L), OD = c(0.05, 1.26, 2.44, 2.37, 2.52, 2.41, 2.09, 
2.22, 0.05, 1.26, 2.52, 2.42, 2.34, 2.28, 2.04, 2.15, 0.05, 1.44, 
2.34, 3.22, 2.82, 2.5, 2.18, 2.34, 0.06, 1.43, 2.33, 3.29, 2.65, 
2.34, 2.17, 2.74, 0.03, 1.04, 2.04, 2.56, 2.89, 2.18, 2.15, 2.49, 
0.04, 1.15, 2.05, 2.49, 2.82, 2.05, 2.08, 2.34, 0.03, 0.81, 2.23, 
2.86, 3.27, 2.87, 2.31, 2.48, 0.04, 0.89, 2.34, 2.82, 3.22, 2.74, 
2.34, 2.45, 0.05, 0.5, 1.03, 1.85, 2.81, 2.41, 2.09, 2.25, 0.03, 
0.45, 0.98, 1.93, 2.81, 2.41, 2.09, 1.93, 0.04, 0.41, 1.01, 1.69, 
2.74, 2.34, 2.1, 2.16, 0.05, 0.48, 1.03, 1.85, 2.89, 2.41, 2.17, 
2.18, 0, 0.17, 0.6, 0.93, 1.22, 2.26, 1.95, 1.77, 0, 0.15, 0.58, 
0.91, 1.25, 2.25, 1.98, 1.54, 0.01, 0.14, 0.43, 0.79, 0.99, 1.78, 
1.7, 1.7, 0.01, 0.15, 0.43, 0.8, 0.94, 1.7, 1.7, 1.79, 0.03, 
1.08, 2.66, 2.5, 2.48, 2.31, 2.19, 1.78, 0.04, 1.08, 2.59, 2.41, 
2.38, 2.38, 2.02, 1.61, 0.04, 1.09, 2.81, 2.42, 2.35, 2.18, 2.11, 
1.76, 0.03, 1.06, 2.78, 2.38, 2.32, 2.22, 1.59, 1.52, 0.03, 0.55, 
1.04, 1.02, 0.97, 0.7, 0.63, 0.63, 0.03, 0.58, 1.07, 1, 0.97, 
0.71, 0.7, 0.7, 0.01, 0.46, 0.98, 1.13, 1.05, 0.53, 0.54, 0.56, 
0, 0.47, 0.92, 1.07, 1, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.06, 1.05, 1.3, 1.15, 
1.15, 1.2, 0.95, 0.85, 0.05, 0.99, 1.24, 1.09, 1.14, 1.14, 0.84, 
0.79, 0.07, 1.24, 1.34, 1.04, 0.99, 0.99, 0.79, 0.69, 0.05, 1.18, 
1.28, 1.13, 0.98, 0.93, 0.78, 0.73, 0, 0.07, 0.1, 0.16, 0.17, 
0.25, 0.67, 0.82, 0.02, 0.07, 0.11, 0.16, 0.18, 0.27, 0.83, 0.83, 
0.03, 0.09, 0.13, 0.17, 0.2, 0.26, 0.94, 0.89, 0.03, 0.08, 0.12, 
0.16, 0.17, 0.27, 0.93, 0.83, 0.05, 1.26, 2.44, 2.37, 2.52, 2.41, 
2.09, 2.22, 0.05, 1.26, 2.52, 2.42, 2.34, 2.28, 2.04, 2.15, 0.05, 
1.44, 2.34, 3.22, 2.82, 2.5, 2.18, 2.34, 0.06, 1.43, 2.33, 3.29, 
2.65, 2.34, 2.17, 2.74, 0.03, 1.04, 2.04, 2.56, 2.89, 2.18, 2.15, 
2.49, 0.04, 1.15, 2.05, 2.49, 2.82, 2.05, 2.08, 2.34, 0.03, 0.81, 
2.23, 2.86, 3.27, 2.87, 2.31, 2.48, 0.04, 0.89, 2.34, 2.82, 3.22, 
2.74, 2.34, 2.45, 0.05, 0.5, 1.03, 1.85, 2.81, 2.41, 2.09, 2.25, 
0.03, 0.45, 0.98, 1.93, 2.81, 2.41, 2.09, 1.93, 0.04, 0.41, 1.01, 
1.69, 2.74, 2.34, 2.1, 2.16, 0.05, 0.48, 1.03, 1.85, 2.89, 2.41, 
2.17, 2.18, 0, 0.17, 0.6, 0.93, 1.22, 2.26, 1.95, 1.77, 0, 0.15, 
0.58, 0.91, 1.25, 2.25, 1.98, 1.54, 0.01, 0.14, 0.43, 0.79, 0.99, 
1.78, 1.7, 1.7, 0.01, 0.15, 0.43, 0.8, 0.94, 1.7, 1.7, 1.79, 
0.03, 1.08, 2.66, 2.5, 2.48, 2.31, 2.19, 1.78, 0.04, 1.08, 2.59, 
2.41, 2.38, 2.38, 2.02, 1.61, 0.04, 1.09, 2.81, 2.42, 2.35, 2.18, 
2.11, 1.76, 0.03, 1.06, 2.78, 2.38, 2.32, 2.22, 1.59, 1.52, 0.03, 
0.55, 1.04, 1.02, 0.97, 0.7, 0.63, 0.63, 0.03, 0.58, 1.07, 1, 
0.97, 0.71, 0.7, 0.7, 0.01, 0.46, 0.98, 1.13, 1.05, 0.53, 0.54, 
0.56, 0, 0.47, 0.92, 1.07, 1, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.06, 1.05, 1.3, 
1.15, 1.15, 1.2, 0.95, 0.85, 0.05, 0.99, 1.24, 1.09, 1.14, 1.14, 
0.84, 0.79, 0.07, 1.24, 1.34, 1.04, 0.99, 0.99, 0.79, 0.69, 0.05, 
1.18, 1.28, 1.13, 0.98, 0.93, 0.78, 0.73, 0, 0.07, 0.1, 0.16, 
0.17, 0.25, 0.67, 0.82, 0.02, 0.07, 0.11, 0.16, 0.18, 0.27, 0.83, 
0.83, 0.03, 0.09, 0.13, 0.17, 0.2, 0.26, 0.94, 0.89, 0.03, 0.08, 
0.12, 0.16, 0.17, 0.27, 0.93, 0.83)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-512L))
```

I am trying to make graphs with facet_wrap which work just fine when I include the data that has just Pb group.

[image: Graphs with Pb group]

But when I try to include second group (Pr) it looks the same...
My code for both groups looks like this:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(Time, OD, colour=Strain)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~Substrate) +
  xlab("Time [h]") + ylab("OD[600]")
```

And the graphs:

[image: Graphs]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. The issue is that your data is identical for both of your `Strain`s.

Comment: In cases like this, I always suggest trying to isolate a difference. If you look at `subset(your_data, Substrate == "Arabinoza" & Time < 5)` for each of your data sets, I think you will see the data is identical except for the `Strain`.